Bochner measurability of a function
Let $T>0$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain. Also $p\in (1,\infty)$ is any number.
I know that $u\in L^{p}((0,T);L^p(\Omega))$ and $\nabla u\in L^{p}((0,T);L^p(\Omega))^N$. How can I show that $u\in L^{p}((0,T);W^{1,p}(\Omega))$?
It is easy to show that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^T \Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}^p\ dt<\infty$. I'm having problems in showing that $u:(0,T)\to W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ is Bochner measurable.
So we need to find a sequence $u_n:(0,T)\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ of simple functions such that $\Vert u_n(t)-u(t)\Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\longrightarrow 0$ for a.a. $t\in (0,T)$.
How can we do that?
Simple functions that are obtained as sum of characteristic functions of cartesian products $A\times B$ with $A\subset (0,T)$ and $B\subset\Omega$ are dense in $L^{p}((0,T)\times\Omega)$ (see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106234/simple-functions-on-a-product-measure-space)...I am stucked here.

Maybe it would be easier to check weak measurability: $t \mapsto f(u(t))$ measurable for all $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$? Such $f$ can be written (I think) as $f(v) = \int_\Omega f_0v + \sum_i f_i \partial_{x_i}v$ with appropriate $f_i$. Then weak measurability follows (which implies strong measurability as $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is separable.
